# Which stats can test differences between two experiments?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test, nested-data, ecology

I have an experiment to look at habitat preferences of beetles and the effect of competition. 
In the first test, a beetle is on his own in an arena and I measured the % of time he spends in each of THREE types of habitat (open, bush and underground).
I repeat this experiment with several beetles.
In the second test, beetles are placed together with a beetle of a competing species in the arena and they are again observed for their % time in each habitat.

I want to test if the amount of time spent in each habitat is affected by the presence of the competitor.

But how can I compare the % time in each of the three habitats when the competitor is absent (test 1) and present (test 2)?
Which test can answer this question? 
Do I need to test the means?

My expectation is that in the presence of the competitor the use of Habitat 2 would increase.
Apologies, I dont know how to import data.

data: 
[image: Habitat 1=]

Comment: Even in test 1, I'm not sure a chi-square test of association would be helpful.  This is because time is not decidedly countable.  For example, if you observe a beetle for 12 hours, if you count where it is each hour you will get a different result than if you count each minute than if you count each second.

Comment: time was standardised - so every test ran for 2 hours and location in every second was recorded ..  does that make it appropriate?

Comment: for me, I wouldn't treat time as something countable...  In your case, I think you might find the hypothesis test with a chi-square analysis isn't very useful simply because you have 7200 (?) observations per subject.  With that many observations, even small differences many be statistically significant. So, I wouldn't put much weight in a small p-value without thinking critically about the difference in percents or time.

Answer (score 0):

Using a $\chi^2$ test you would always check 33 %. A linear model would be able to capture a more complex situation. With it you could set up hypotheses to test the % time in each habitat and whether is changes with number of competitors present.

Comment: Wouldn't it be problematic for the linear model that the percents in a scenario always add up to 100%?  That it, as the percent in one habitat increases, the percent in another must decrease.  So the observations of the dependent variable are not independent?

Comment: @SalMangiafico you are right, I overlooked that. Maybe if the variable was not transformed and kept in raw values (time) it would work. Afterwards the raw results could be transformed into percentages.

Comment: I think there is a type of model that is used for data that sum to a whole. Unfortunately I don't remember the name and can't find anything online about it.  ...  Whether as a percent or as a time, I would think that focusing on just one habitat would be approachable with a linear model, beta regression, or something similar.

Comment: It might be "compositional data"